# Adding View Programmatically from ViewController super class doesn't show in front

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

I have a BaseViewController that my UIViewControllers extend so i can have explicit functions that i dont need to rewrite. Something i would like would be a functions such as `self.showSpinner()` and the viewController would show the spinner

My Code looks like this

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

var actvIndicator : UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.actvIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .WhiteLarge)
    self.actvIndicator.color = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.actvIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.actvIndicator.frame  = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, 100, 100);
    self.actvIndicator.center = self.view.center
    self.actvIndicator .startAnimating()
    self.view.addSubview(self.actvIndicator)
    self.actvIndicator.bringSubviewToFront(self.view)

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
}
func showSpinner(){

    self.actvIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func hideSpinner(){
    self.actvIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
}
```

And my viewcontrollers looks like this

```
class MyProjectViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.showSpinner()
    }
}
```

`MyProjectViewController` have `UITableView` that fills the entire screen. When i set `tblProjects.alpha = 0` i can see the spinner. But i want it in the front.

i also tried `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.actvIndicator)`

What am i missing?

Comment: Without studying this in detail - shouldn't self.actvIndicator.bringSubviewToFront(self.view) be the other way round?

Comment: @DavidDoyle I tried that already, and the result is the same. Nothing to show

Comment: Next question: have you tried the start animating call after adding it to the superview?

Comment: Some updates to my post. Turns out it it adds the activity indicator. But it just comes behind the UITableView that i have in `MyProjectViewController`. I can see it when i put the alpha to 0

Answer (score 2):

A couple quick notes before I get into what I think your problem is:

1. When you add a subview it is automatically added to the top layer, no need for the `bringSubviewToFront:` in `viewDidLoad:` (which is being used wrong anyway).
2. You should not set view frames in viewDidLoad: (e.g. centering a view). Frames are not setup yet, so you should move that to `viewWillAppear:` or some other variant.

Now your issue is most likely a view hierarchy problem (further confirmed by your comment) and thus can probably be fixed by pushing the spinner to the front every time you want it to be shown, like:

```
func showSpinner() {
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.actvIndicator)
    self.actvIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, I tried it. But moved the initalizing of the frames to `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: Are you adding additional views programmatically at all? Like in IB is your table a container?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here stands on the fact that table view is draw after you are calling `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.actvIndicator)`. A possible workaround for this is to call bringSubviewToFront when showing the spinner

```
func showSpinner(){

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.actvIndicator)
    self.actvIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```